# Unable to import a pretrained model after calling Keras.backend.clear_session()

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a model with new data samples in each iteration in a loop in keras (using tensorflow backend). Due to GPU memory error after some iterations, I appended K.clear_session(). However, after one iteration, the code throws the error:

```
'Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: ' + e.args[0])
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(7, 7, 3, 64), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

If I remove K.clear_session() at end, there is no error. Is there anyone who can explain why this error comes in second iteration?

I tried other methods (for gpu release) but none of them worked and this is my last option. But it throws error. I have pasted an example code which can produce the error. Please NOTE that this is not the actual code, I just made an example to reproduce the error which I am facing in actual code.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import random
seed_value= 0
import os
import keras
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(seed_value)
random.seed(0)
np.random.seed(0)
from keras import backend as K
from keras.datasets import cifar10

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
for i in range(3):
    base_model = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(weights='imagenet', input_shape=(32, 32, 3),
                                               include_top=False)
    x = base_model.output
    x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax',
                               kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(seed=4))(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)
    y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
    y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

    for layer in base_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size=1024,epochs=1,verbose=1)
    K.clear_session()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sirshad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1092, in _run
    subfeed, allow_tensor=True, allow_operation=False)
  File "C:\Users\sirshad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3490, in as_graph_element
    return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
  File "C:\Users\sirshad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3569, in _as_graph_element_locked
    raise ValueError("Tensor %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(7, 7, 3, 64), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/codes/experiments-AL/breakhis/40X-M-B/codes-AL/error_debug.py", line 22, in <module>
    include_top=False)
  File "C:\Users\sirshad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\applications\__init__.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return base_fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sirshad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\applications\resnet50.py", line 32, in ResNet50
    return resnet50.ResNet50(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sirshad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras_applications\resnet50.py", line 291, in ResNet50
    model.load_weights(weights_path)
  File "C:\Users\sirshad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 1544, in load_weights
    saving.load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f, self.layers)
  File "C:\Users\sirshad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\saving.py", line 806, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group
    K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)
  File "C:\Users\sirshad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 2784, in batch_set_value
    get_session().run(assign_ops, feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "C:\Users\sirshad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\sirshad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1095, in _run
    'Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: ' + e.args[0])
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(7, 7, 3, 64), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with "this exact" code?

Comment: Hi Daniel, this is the exact problem which I get using another code. Are you able to reproduce the error from code given above? Can you suggest any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to overcome this issue by saving the imagenet pre-trained model to disk and then loading everytime in loop after I call tf.keras.backend.clear_session(). So saving the base model to file and then loading works. But I am still confused why it did not work before with

> base_model = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50